# How to check server load in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application in asp.NET. In this app, users can perform create, add, edit and delete any particular records. Where as, that data is being stored in a local (school) server. Now the main think I want to know that how to identify the percentage of load on server when any number of users trying to perform operations?

Like if server has a capacity of 100 users at a time and there are 60 users performing operations at a time, then server should show 60% load.

Comment: Performance Counters can tell you server metrics

Answer (score 0):

please refer [load testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing).

```
You can scale out number of user and the graphical representation is good.
You can create test case for each server hit.
```